# PHP errors Message: Undefined index: From using MX Notify Control

Tags: extension, notification

getting these errors when an entry is updated. It is supposed to send an email to a mailing list using mx notify control:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: From

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1584

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: From

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1190

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 885

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1747

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: From

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1190

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 885

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1747

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: From

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1190

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 885

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Return-Path

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1747

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tanyacol/admin/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/admin/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 414
```

Comment: Can you check the MX Notify Settings if having "From Email" for that notification.

Comment: Yes the From name and email are both filled in on the settings page. I am sending to a mailing list so the to email is blank and the mailing list is selected.

Comment: I have tried php and SMTP and get the same results.  It is like it send the email to the first person on the list and then not the rest.  I believe in the errors above I am getting a set of errors for each email on the list.  The bigger the list the more errors are displayed.

Comment: which version of EE you are using?

Comment: EE ver 2.6.0
 & 
MX Notify Control 2.4.6 (current)

Comment: If emails are working at other area then there may be something in MX Notify Control which isn't setting email headers properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple php errors when saving an entry](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13758/multiple-php-errors-when-saving-an-entry)

Answer (score 1):

(as provided by the extension developer) The proper "To Email" field syntax is {author_email}, not {mbr_email} as it says in the instructions for the extension settings. I am assuming the same goes for the other variables.