# MX Notify Control: multiple php errors when saving an entry

Tags: email, php-errors, mx-notify

I just updated to EE2.7, and I'm getting this error when I try to save an entry:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1588
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1194
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   Return-Path Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 889
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1588
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1194
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   Return-Path Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 889
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: From Filename:
>   libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1588
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1194
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   Return-Path Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 889
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1588
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1194
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   Return-Path Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 889
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1588
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   From Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1194
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index:
>   Return-Path Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 889
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/content/19/5501119/html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>   Filename: libraries/Functions.php Line Number: 809
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/content/19/5501119/html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>   Filename: libraries/Functions.php Line Number: 809
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/content/19/5501119/html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>   Filename: libraries/Functions.php Line Number: 414

I'm using MX Notify Control to notify users when an entry they've authored is updated, and it looks like trying to fire off the emails is causing this error. I've updated to the latest version of every add-on I'm using, including MX Notify, and I can't find any info on these errors. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

As error messages indicate, its due to FROM value which doesn't get by Email library. Can you check the MX Notify Control setting for that channel entry notification if having "From Name" and "From Name".

Answer (score 3):

I have chance to make test - the reason of this can be wrong tag in **TO** field. 
For example, for Entry Update/Create trigger needs to use *author_email* instead of *mbr_email*.

I will try soon make better example in docs (and with additional notifications inside the add-on to prevent such situation).

Comment: Any updates here? Not sure what the fix you are suggesting is.

Comment: could you please send me screenshot of your settings?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. Status update requests are best kept in comments.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel it is exactly answer on question - people set wrong email into TO field. Because of this field is leave empty and MX Notify can't send email.

Comment: @MaxLazar that comment was posted on Aaron's 'answer' below was posted. It was later converted to a comment, so it wasn't related to your answer, which is indeed an answer.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel my bad. don't understand it. sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here (as provided by the extension developer) is that the proper "To Email" field syntax is {author_email}, not {mbr_email} as it says in the instructions for the extension settings. I am assuming the same goes for the other variables.